# Reverse MS-Access Format Function

Tags: sql, format, ms-access-2007

I have a field within an Access 2007 database which contains either a `0` or a `1`.

When displaying a view, I need to format the field as `Yes/No`.

My issue is that I can't use `FORMAT(Field,"Yes/No")` as the `1` and `0` are the wrong way round i.e.:

`0 = No` `1 = Yes` is how the format function works.

`1 = No` `0 = Yes` is how my data is formatted.

Is there anyway to reserve or manipulate the `FORMAT` function in a way that when a query is run, the query will display my Yes/No the correct way round?

Comment: Something like FORMAT(ABS(Field-1), "Yes/No")?

Comment: @RichardHansell Perfect thank you. Stick it as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FORMAT(ABS(Field-1), "Yes/No")
```

This works because ABS(1-1) = 0 and ABS(0-1) = 1.  In other words your 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0, so it changes the number to have the "right" value (as far as MS-Access is concerned) before using the format function.